# Is this a reasonable use of a SortedList with duplicates

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I have the following code to make a list with duplicate keys.
The list is at most 150 items, and the key value is 0..100.

```
public SortedList<double, Sector> sectors;
// ...
double theKey = 100.0 - sortValue;
while (sectors.Keys.Contains(theKey)) theKey += 0.00001;
sectors.Add(theKey, newSector);
```

Is this a reasonable hack or is there a better class to use?

Comment: Questions asking for opinions are considered off-topic.  Everyone is going to have a different definition of "reasonable".

Comment: Take a look at the ToLookup method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.7.2 This allows many values for the same key... but depends if you need sorting or not

Comment: `theKey += 0.00001;` That is an odd way to solve the problem. `Dictionary<int, List<Sector>>` would be more traditional (I'd be reluctant to key anything by a `double`).

Comment: Thanks - ToLookup got me thinking and I avoided the sort issue by adding a method to the class that returns this list sorted using OrderByDescendig.

Comment: not clear yet, but why aint u using random values?